# Truth tables representing boolean equations

Tags: boolean, equation, truthtable

Please see the attached photo of a question I am confused on. Please do note I am not looking for the answer, but maybe a sense of direction of how I can solve this please!

I do not know how to solve this and would like to know how please.

[image: image of Question]

Comment: Start substituting 1 or 0 for `A` and `B` into the formula and see what the results are. Then figure out what table matches the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve the question:
Namely: Proving the truth table for the given expression is equal to the other truth table by drawing it out, venn diagrams, or deduction:
This link here should help out, and gives examples:
https://www.ied.edu.hk/has/phys/de/de-ba.htm

Bare in mind your lecturer/prof may have a preference on how you solve these and allocate marks accordingly (assuming this is for an assignment), perhaps you missed a lesson on when you were taught this?